# What does the answer to the "What's my name" puzzle spell when viewed from behind?

Tags: fez

When [the "What's my name" puzzle](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/62421/21177) is completed and the answer is spelled above the door, what is spelled when viewed from the opposite direction?

I'm really curious as to what it says and why the game only recognises the rear view to complete the puzzle...

Comment: Did you [try translating it yourself](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/62482/what-is-fezs-alphabet)?

Answer (score 1):

**This is what it looks like from behind:**

[image: behind]

**It [spells](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/62486/21177) "METATRON" vertically if you tilt your head to the left.**