# What's the secret in the room with a floating purple block with Fez text on it?

Tags: fez

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to solve the “What's my name” security question puzzle](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/62421/how-to-solve-the-whats-my-name-security-question-puzzle)

In this room, there is a huge hanging block with two blocks of text written in Fez's alphabet. There are eight blocks on the ground, which I assume I need to arrange in some fashion to get the right answer.

[Room with purple blocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2et3.png)

I translated what's on the block:

> Please answer this security question: what's my name? Security question hint: my first half is what it is; my second half is half of what made it.

But I can't for the life of me figure out what the answer to the riddle is! So what is the answer to the riddle?

Comment: Answered here: [How to solve the “What's my name” security question puzzle](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/62421/21177)

Comment: Ah close this then. :)